# Direction of gravitational field in Hemisphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity

Supposing we have a uniformly mass distributed hemisphere of some radius, so what will be direction of gravitational field throughout the flat surface of hemisphere? And why?

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centers_of_gravity_in_non-uniform_fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In the flat, you will feel it falls down the mountain side to the center*
Due the direction of gravity would be at the center of mass.

A picture is worth a thousand words.

[image]

In a uniformly mass distributed hemisphere of radius r, the center of mass is given by geometric centroid. The geometric centroid of an heisphere is then given by `3/8 * r`

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hemisphere.html

Comment: You're assuming that the direction of the gravitational acceleration always points towards the centre of mass, and in general this is not true.